# Transformation between normal distribution and standard normal distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

My professor wrote the following two relationships

$X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)\Rightarrow a X + b \sim N(\mu + b,a^2 \sigma^2)$.

$X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)\Rightarrow(X-\mu)/\sigma\sim N(0 ,1)$.

I am confused about the second relation because if we assume the first relation is correct, then the second relation becomes $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2 )\Rightarrow (X-\mu)/\sigma\sim N(\mu -\mu/\sigma,1)$.

Comment: The first one should be $N(a\mu + b, a^2 \sigma^2)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's find the distribution of the first one
$$P(aX+b\leq x)=P(X\leq\frac{x-b}{a})=\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{x-b}{a}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dy$$
set $z=ay+b$ so $y=(z-b)/a$
$$P(aX+b\leq x)=\int_{-\infty}^x\frac{1}{a}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(z-(a\mu+b))^2}{2\sigma^2a^2}}dz=\int_{-\infty}^x\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2a^2}}e^{-\frac{(z-(a\mu+b))^2}{2\sigma^2a^2}}dz$$
So $aX+b \sim \mathcal{N}(a\mu+b,\sigma^2a^2)$. Now for the second one
$$P(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\leq x)=P(X\leq x\sigma + \mu)=\int_{-\infty}^{x\sigma+\mu}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dy$$
Set $z=(y-\mu)/\sigma$ so $y=\sigma z + \mu$
$$P(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\leq x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}\sigma\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}dz=\int_{-\infty}^{x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}dz$$
So $(X-\mu)/\sigma \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$.